# Seeking tips to install replacement Camry door handle: rod insertion

Tags: camry, door

I'm attempting to [replace a 98 Camry door handle](http://www.toyotanation.com/forum/103-3rd-4th-generation-1992-1996-1997-2001/289903-door-handle-removal-install-diy-warning-56k.html).  I'm able to clip the cylinder lock's plastic clip to the corresponding rod.

Now I am seeking tips / tricks to insert terminals of door handle's other connecting rod.  Initially, I tried leaving this rod in the door and tried to inserting the terminal into the handle opening: I was not able to do so because it is difficult to position and squeeze it in: .   So the rod was disconnected from the door and pliers were required to squeeze rod into handle's opening.

Photo of rod that clipped into the handle:

[image]

Now the challenge is to clip the rod's other end back onto the inner door.

This approach is very different from the [approach shown on Youtube](https://youtu.be/HyhMp5zvvIw?t=5m30s): the rod is left connected to the door assembly and the rod is inserted (jammed) into the new handle assembly.

If you have done this before successfully please indicate this in your response: any tips are trick are highly appreciated.  Thank you